# Win program to show git repositories status

Tags: windows, git

my question is: is there a program that only shows the status of the various repositories I have in my Pc (or a list of them)?

thanks  in advance

Comment: Aside from being [off-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) you're pretty vague with any requirements. For instance you could just use the git client to show the status of an individual repository. You might want to spend some time thinking about your requirements and maybe try the software recommendation exchange afterwards (be sure to read what makes a good question for them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the tool [SCM Notifier](https://github.com/pocorall/scm-notifier) which monitors Subversion and git working copies/cloned repositories and shows if it needs an update (yellow icon)

[image]

Here you can update them via [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/download/)